# laravel custom pagination override doesn't work in active class

Tags: laravel, pagination

I wrote customize css for laravel pagination. All is work well except active class.I want to change the background-color of active of class to orange.

Here is my css

```
.div_blogspage_pag>ul>li>a{
    color: #cc6633;
    border-color: #cc6633;
}
.active:active{
    background-color: #cc6633; !important;
}
.div_blogspage_pag>ul>li.active>a,.div_blogspage_pag>ul>li.active>a:hover{
    background-color: #cc6633;
    color: white;
    border-color: #cc6633;
}
.div_blogspage_pag>ul>li:hover>a{
    color: white;
    border-color: #cc6633;
    background-color: #cc6633;
}
```

laravel blade

```
<div class="div_blogspage_pag">
    {{$articles->links()}}
</div>
```

Here is output all is fine except active class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSpLw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it.

```
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
    color: #6db91c;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.pagination>li>a:hover, .pagination>li>span:hover, .pagination>li>a:focus, .pagination>li>span:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6db91c;
    border-color: #6db91c
}

.pagination>.active>a, .pagination>.active>span, .pagination>.active>a:hover, .pagination>.active>span:hover, .pagination>.active>a:focus, .pagination>.active>span:focus {
    z-index: 2;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #6db91c;
    border-color: #6db91c
}

.pagination>.disabled>span, .pagination>.disabled>span:hover, .pagination>.disabled>span:focus, .pagination>.disabled>a, .pagination>.disabled>a:hover, .pagination>.disabled>a:focus {
    color: #000; background-color: #fff; border-color: #000; cursor: not-allowed
}
```

Comment: The active button its still blue